# How do you unsplit an editor, go back from 2 code views to 1, same with terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you unsplit an editor, go back from 2 code views to 1, same with terminal.

Answer (score 138):

### Editor Groups

To "unsplit" [editor groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups) **without closing any open files**, use the menu-bars: `View > Editor Layout > Single` (or, while in the editor, press and release ALT and then type `vls`).

Editor groups are also closed by default *when they become empty*. You can empty an editor group by closing tabs/files or by dragging all of the tabs from that group to another.

Hints:

- Grabbing the area to the right of the tabs allows you to drag/drop all tabs in a group at once.
- The "Open Editors" section of the "Explorer" panel lets you use CTRL and SHIFT to select and drag/close multiple editors at once. (If you don't have an "Open Editors" section, use the "..." menu of the Explorer panel to enable it.)

### Terminal Groups

[Terminals work differently than editor groups](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7504) and are more limited:

You can open new terminal groups by pressing the '+' icon in the terminal tab of the panel.

"Splitting" a terminal (done by clicking the split icon in the terminal tab of the panel) really just *opens an additional terminal* in the same group and displays it side-by-side with the others in the group.

So, two ways to "unsplit" terminals:

- *Kill* terminals (e.g. with the trashcan icon) until there is only one left in the group.
- Switch to a new terminal group with only a single terminal in it.

(as of Visual Studio Code version 1.29.1)

Comment: For those who prefer to skip creating another key binding, you can type the command search shortcut (ctrl-shift-p I believe, I have mine remapped to ctrl-shift-a), type 'single' and select the command mentioned above (using arrow keys + enter, though for me it was the only option so arrow keys were unnecessary).

Comment: Type 'exit' into terminals to close. As of version 1.46, the trashcan icon closes the group.

Comment: @JoeManlove Thanks; it looks like in version 1.56.2, the trashcan is only closing a single terminal, now.

Comment: For editor splits, you can also bind a key to `workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle`.

Answer (score 29):

**By mouse**

To close or unsplit a split Editor you need to

- either close all the tabs in the split side you want to close
- or right-click on one of the tabs in the section you want to close and select Close All.

**By keyboard**
To close or unsplit split Terminals:

type `exit` in the terminal you want to close.

**Note**

The split Editors will not close when you close the tabs if you have in your settings `"workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroup" : false`

Comment: "type `exit` in the terminal you want to close" pefect !

Answer (score 21):

#### Editors:

`View: Join Editor Group with Next Group` **`workbench.action.joinTwoGroups`**

`View: Join All Editor Groups` **`workbench.action.joinAllGroups`**

#### Terminal:

`Terminal: Kill the Active Terminal Instance` **`workbench.action.terminal.kill`**

Answer (score 12):

`ctrl+\` to split
`ctrl+w` to unsplit

Comment: Nice :3 Thank You! The ctrl+w should be in tooltip after pointing the mouse on the split button.

Comment: The mac equivalents for split and unsplit are, respectively, cmd+\ and cmd+w.

Comment: `ctrl+w` closes the current file. This is not that same as unsplitting. @teichert's answer demonstrates collapsing down to a single view.

Answer (score 8):

F1 > View: Join Editors of Two Groups

Answer (score 1):

Default keybindungs for join/split **editor** **(macOS)**

**join** current view/group with next group (just press multiple times if you have multiple groups):

`alt+cmd+1`

**split** current view/group:

`alt+cmd+2`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this "VSCode irritation no. 1", you also have, beside "View: Join Editor Group with Next Group", a way to *avoid* the issue entirely, with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)

> ### [New setting to disable editor group splitting on drag & drop](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/8ddd24791f80161c260cb598803320428b7ce2f0/release-notes/v1_52.md#new-setting-to-disable-editor-group-splitting-on-drag--drop)

> A new setting `workbench.editor.splitOnDragAndDrop` allows to disable editor group splitting when using drag & drop of editors.
>
> There is also a way to toggle this conditionally during the drag and drop operation when you press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (macOS) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (Windows, Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Split current file (`Ctrl+\`) is a combination I can constantly hitting by mistake so I just removed the shortcut.

1. Command Palette
2. Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)
3. Paste the following object in the array:

   {
   "key": "ctrl+oem_5",
   "command": "-workbench.action.splitEditor"
   }

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Alt + RightArrow` (to split / to "go forward")

`Ctrl + Alt + LeftArrow` (to join / to "go back")

Comment: Can you add a documentation link and/or version support range?