# How to combine all editor tabs into a single editor window in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a key command to move all open editors in VSCode to a single editor window? Or similar?

Most of the time, I have two or three editor windows open in my monitor and 1-5 tabs per editor window. However, when I switch to the laptop screen, all of them are much too small to be useful. Is there a key command that moves all open editor tabs to a single pane? Or a command that's close enough to save me some tedium?

(There is a command to move the active editor to another one, `shft` + `alt` + `<num>` in Linux, but I can't find a command to do this with all open tabs.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the menus in VSCode by going to `View -> Editor Layout -> Single`.

There is no default keybinding, so I created one that mimicked the existing pattern for moving editor panes. On Mac that was `ctrl` + `cmd` + `←/→` for moving left and right, so I mapped `Single` to up arrow.

Open the [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) settings page, search for `single`. You want the `View: Single Column Editor Layout` command. Double-click to set a new keybinding: `ctrl` + `cmd` + `↓`. This binding had two conflicts, but looking at their context they would not conflict with my use case.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53549702) by [teichert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3780389/teichert) for more on Editor Groups and Terminal Groups.